# Cordova: How to add multiple JS files into <js-module> if them require('./each-other') ?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm building a cordova plugin and want to split my JS layer on N files:

- www/myPlugin.js
- www/myPlugin/utils.js
- www/myPlugin/core.js

In www/myPlugin.js I want to export the functionality exported by utils.js and core.js:

```
module.exports = {
  utils: require('./myPlugin/utils'),
  core: require('./myPlugin/core')
}
```

This is so easy when working in Node, but I don't know whether this would work in Cordova given that I have to declare a `<js-module>` for each JS file, and once those files are loaded in the app (by means of a XHR) they cannot "find" to each other. From the doc:

> At load time, code in cordova.js uses XHR to read each file and inject a  tag into HTML

Can I just add in plugin.xml a `<js-module>` for each JS file? If so, would `require('./myPlugin/core.js')` just work when Cordova reads it in "www/myPlugin.js"?

Or should I rather create a bundled JS file with browserify and place it into www/ with a single `<js-module>`?

The question is: if I add two JS files (a.js and b.js) how could I `require('./b')` from a.js once both files are handled by Cordova? Should I use `cordova.require()`? I don't want that each JS file exports stuff to `window` namespace.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it's much better to create a single browserified JS file and use it within a single `<js-module>`.